# Wireguard no internet on ubuntu but works fine for the very same config on my android phone and on windows 10

Tags: networking, server, vpn, amazon-ec2, wireguard

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 for both the server and the client and have used an EC2 AWS instance for the server. I've also used this installer for installing wireguard on AWS:

https://github.com/pprometey/wireguard_aws

so I'm pretty sure there are no mistakes and I have tried both /24 and /32 for subnets to no avail.
I've also set the MTU to 1360 because it makes somethings that don't get through work and that got it to work on the phone after trying many different MTU's.

does anyone know how to resolve that problem please? I'm out of tricks...

(SERVER)

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.50.0.1
SaveConfig = false
PrivateKey = (hidden)
ListenPort = (hidden)
PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip link set dev wg0 mtu 1360; ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1360;
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;

[Peer]
PublicKey = (hidden)
PresharedKey = (hidden)
AllowedIPs = 10.50.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = (hidden)
PresharedKey = (hidden)
AllowedIPs = 10.50.0.3/24
```

===================================

(CLIENT)

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = (hidden)
Address = 10.50.0.3/24
DNS = 94.140.14.14,94.140.15.15
PostUp = ip link set dev wg0 mtu 1360; ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1360; ip link set dev wlan0 mtu 1360;
MTU = 1360
[Peer]
PublicKey = (hidden)
PresharedKey = (hidden)
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = (hidden)
PersistentKeepalive=25
```

Comment: Did you try to change the `/24` to `/32` in the last line of the server configuration?

Comment: this is the last server configuration and every time I do it I reboot both machines

Comment: For me the question is not very clear: your ubuntu client is unable to connect to your server? can you ping your servers wireguard ip? are ubuntu client and android client using different private and public keys? don't you need to leave a blank field inside your DNS adresses line after the comma? can you ping the public endpoint address with your ubuntu client? any firewall from client (or server) side blocking you perhaps? at your Endpoint line did you also add the port number at the end? In your first Address line the subnet is missing: 10.50.0.1/24